# Assigned barcode Reader value to Text input control in powerapps

Tags: powerapps

I have a form in power apps which will add hardware assets and log the history of the assets.
To try and reduce any user error I'm using an initial input where the user will scan a barcode and store the service tag.

Within the form I have a service tag card and a text input called DataCardValue1 and a BarcodeReader.

Is there or would anyone have a current solution to use the output of the barcode reader and store that value within the datacard?

Comment: See if this helps: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Populate-a-text-field-with-a-barcode-scanner/td-p/1337744

Comment: Already tried that. It seems as though they have updated how its done cause every answer to the question is from 2021 so there's not many current answers. Thank you though

Comment: On the OnScan event: `UpdateContext({ scannedItem: First(BarcodeReader.Barcodes).Value });`  
Then on your card or Text input, change the Default to `scannedItem`